# $f$ integrable iff $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n \lambda(\{x\in[0,1]:|f(x)|\geq 2^n\})<\infty$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be a measurable function. I want to show 
$f$ is integrable $\Leftrightarrow \sum_{n=1}^\infty 2^n \lambda(\{x\in[0,1]:|f(x)|\geq 2^n\})<\infty$.
I started with $\int_0^1 |f| d\lambda=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_{2^{-n}}^{2^{-n+1}}|f| d\lambda$. How can I go on now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key here is to notice that
$$\int_{[0,1]}|f|\,d\lambda = \int_0^\infty \lambda(\{|f| > t\})\,dt = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_{2^{n-1}}^{2^{n}} \lambda(\{|f|>t\}) d t$$
Now notice that the function $t\mapsto \lambda(|f|>t)$ is decreasing and thus
$$
2^{n-1} \lambda(\{|f|>2^{n}\}) \leq \int_{2^{n-1}}^{2^{n}} \lambda(\{|f|>t\}) \,d t \leq 2^{n-1} \lambda(\{|f|>2^{n-1}\})
$$
for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 1}$.
What you want to prove follows immediately from the above double inequality.

Comment: Could you tell how you wrote $2^{n-1}$ in either of the extreme sides of the relation? I got that due to the decreasing nature, $\lambda(\{|f|>2^{n}\})$ is placed in the left side but I am not getting why it would be $2^{n-1}$ along with it and not $2^n$ , say. Actually I wanted to use your approach in my related [query](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4770247/1074816) where there is the additional  $t^{p-1}\lambda(\{|f|>t\})$ and was not getting what to place in the left and right side of the integral. Would be grateful if you could say a thing or two. Thanks.

Comment: @User1865345 This is a an application of the fact that if $f$ is decreasing on $[a,b]$ then by integrating the inequality $f(x) \geq f(b)$ over $[a,b]$ we get $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx \geq f(b)\cdot (b-a)$$ Here we apply this on $[2^{n-1}, 2^n]$.

Comment: Thanks, Giorgos, for the reply. That would mean in LHS, it would be $f(2^{n-1}) \times 2^{n-1}(2-1).$ Similarly, in RHS, it would be $f(2^n)\times 2^{n-1}.$ Could you advise me on how to use this decreasing property of $\lambda(\{|f|>t\})$ along with $t^{p-1}$ i.e. $t^{p-1}\lambda(\{|f|>t\})? $ I also want to make an inequality relation like above in this case but I am stuck on how to deal with $t^{p-1}.$ Thanks for the clarification again (already +1 ed).

Comment: @User1865345 You could use the inequality $\lfloor t \rfloor \leq t \leq \lfloor t\rfloor + 1$ to first bound the term $t^{p-1}$ inside the integral and then use the monotonicity of $\mu(|f|>t)$ to further bound the resulting series, but I haven't worked out the details so I might be wrong.

Comment: Thanks again Giorgos. I would work on your hint and let you know. Appreciate your feedback.